# In a View, how I display only the first image from a field that allows multiple?

Tags: views, 9

I have a very basic view, that outputs the title and images. Some nodes have 2-3 images in them, but when I create a view it outputs all the images. How do I display only the first image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently it will display all images if you have multiple in the node. The only option is to set the settings in the "Content: Image" setting to show only 1 under multiple image settings.

Comment: More specifically, the "Multiple field settings" has a "Display" field that is set to 0, which includes all images by default. Like you said, setting this to 1 solves the problem.